# Unacceptable certificate:CN=GTS CA 1C3, O=Google Trust Services LLC, C=US

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

I have a flutter application with Firebase and I'm trying to add Phone authentication to it but whenever I try to send an OTP code an error message appears says:
SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Unacceptable certificate:CN=GTS CA 1C3, O=Google Trust Services LLC, C=US
D/FirebaseAuth(10240): Invoking original failure callbacks after phone verification failure for +962795231474, error - An internal error has occurred. [ Unacceptable certificate:CN=GTS CA 1C3, O=Google Trust Services LLC, C=US ]

```
ElevatedButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor:
            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 12.0),
            ),
            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onPressed: () async {
            
            String phoneNumber = _phoneNumberController.text.trim();

            await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
              phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
              verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
                
                await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
              },
              verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
               
                print('Error: ${e.message}');
              },
              codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                setState(() {
                  _verificationId = verificationId;
                });
              },
              codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
                setState(() {
                  _verificationId = verificationId;
                });
              },
              timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
            );
          },
          child: const Text(
            "Log In With OTP",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Have you tried adding sha1 and sha256 keys to your firebase?